# How to know the source of route redirection in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a navigation guard in place `(main.js)`, which redirects certain routes if a condition is met:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (conditionMet)
      next('/another-route');
  else
      next();
})
```

Now how can I know which `route` was redirected to `/another-route`?

The `from` object in, In-component navigation guard of `/another-route` doesn't point to the actual referrer, instead it points to the route which referred the `redirected` route. Sounds confusing?

In simple terms, If `route A` had a button which on click goes to `route B` and then `route B` is redirected to `route C`. The `from` object in `C` has details of `A` instead of `B`.

How do I know which route was actually redirected to `C`?

```
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
      console.log(from);
      /* */
      next();
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it that way. But you can do a workaround by using query params in `/another-route` that points to route B. So it will be like `/another-route?next=%2Froute-b`. And after that, you can just use `this.$router.redirect(this.$route.query.next)`

This how I do it in my program if unauthorized user accessing some pages, e.g `/customer/1`. I use `r` for the query params.

```
beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
  let access_token = Vue.cookie.get('access_token')
  if (access_token == null) {
    // user doesn't have access token, redirect to login
    if (from.name !== 'login') { // prevent append /r if from is login page itself
      next({ name: 'login', query: { r: to.fullPath } })
    }
    next({ name: 'login' })
  } else {
    // user has access token, user can open the page
    next()
  }
},
```

The link will become `/login?r=%2Fcustomer%2F1`

And in login.vue

```
onSubmit () {
  this.submitting = true
  let { username, password } = this
  this.$api.POST('auth/login', { username, password })
    .then(response => {
      let { id, access_token } = response.data
      this.setCookie(id, access_token)
      this.$router.replace(this.$route.query.r)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
        // show error that username or password is invalid
      }
    })
    .finally(() => {
      this.submitting = false
    })
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution. Just curious: Why are you setting cookies from the client side? Does this have any benefits?

Comment: @saibbyweb It is because this project is fully separated from the server side and running on different domain. The server authorization is using Laravel Passport with bearer token. I need to save the token in vue, so I go with cookie. Another alternative is using localstorage, but I use cookie because this way I can set the expiration date.

Comment: But idk if there is better solution, this is just what I came up with though.

Comment: Alright. If you don't mind, you can hit me up on skype @ `live:suhaibkhan.work` It seems like you are working with Vue just like me. May be we can share some approaches/techniques to make better products.